# Setting OG with Services module

Tags: organic-groups, services

I am trying to `POST` a node to my site and make it group member.

POST body looks like this:

```
{
   "title":"Update",
   "type":"mesurement",
   "uid":"4",
    "og_group_ref": {
        "und": [{
            "target_id": "20"
        }]
    },
    "field_records": {
        "und": [{
            "value": "22"
        }, {
            "value": "25"
        }, {
            "value": "65"
        }, {
            "value": "12"
        }]
    }
}
```

Yet every time I get an error saying:

```
{
    "form_errors": {
        "og": "You must select one or more groups for this content."
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

Field settings are:

Default widget type: Select list

Administrator widget type: Autocomplete

Number of values: 1

Mode: Organic groups

Comment: Have you tried posting it with "value" instead of "target_id", I know when posting term references I was trying to use "tid" or "target_id" and kept tripping up on that b/c it actually needed the structure setup more like the form post instead of the output. I will try to test that on my dev box in a little while and answer for sure but it's worth a try :)

Comment: @burnsjeremy I tried "value" did not work :(

Comment: Have you tried using json structure like this: "und": "20" and not have the target id, looking back at a publish module using services that I've been tinkering with that is how I add new fields with select lists. Other things to check, make sure you have the right gid and make sure that your services user is part of that group for the structure I just mentioned. I would guess the autocomplete way would probably work better for the case your services user is not part of that group but the structure would be closer to what the answer below has then.

Comment: I guess I should also ask what version of Services are you using and OG version. Also are you using something like REST Console to test the output, if not I recommend getting the Chrome extension and use that to test the correct structure.

Comment: @burnsjeremy Yes I have octachecked if everything is all right

Comment: Services Version: 7.x-3.12+2-dev
OG Version: 7.x-2.7
And the node is created just with no relations to the group

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same troubles. Seems to me as far as my limited debugging skills go, that when drupal_process_form calls

```
$form = form_builder($form_id, $form, $form_state);
```

the values for `$form_state[‘input’][‘og_group_ref’]` don’t get passed through into `$form`. So I suspect I need to understand `form_builder` better to figure out why the values coming in aren’t getting transferred through. Ultimately when we get to `og_form_group_reference_validate`, `$form_state['values’][‘og_group_ref’]` doesn’t exist.

So, what I’m going to try for now (and seems to be working) is let `og_form_group_reference_validate` look in `$form_state[‘input’]` in addition to `$form_state[‘values’]`, as `og_group_ref` still exists there.

Here’s a gist of my patch:

https://gist.github.com/housser/ba03c50f670dc5310520

Answer (score 0):

The JSON that you need to send for `og_group_ref` is dependant on the *widget* you have selected on your **manage fields** page for your content type. For example, if you're using an Autocomplete widget, then you need to send JSON like this:

```
"og_group_ref": {
    "und": [{
        "target_id": "... (123)"
    }]
}
```

You can put anything in place of the `...`, but the entity id must be wrapped in parenthesis.

Comment: Added my specification to the description

Comment: For a select list widget see https://www.drupal.org/node/2570203#comment-11117681