# I am not able to assign a group to a node while creating it

Tags: 7, services

We are using Drupal 7.39 and Services 7.x-3.12 .

We are also using organic groups 7.x-2.7 and while creating a node of type attendance (which is a group content). We are not able to assign a group to it.

We are passing the following parameters:

```
{
  "type": "attendance",    
  "title": "Testing Attendance",  
  "field_attendance_status":{  
  "und":{  
    "tid":3  
  }},  
  "og_group_ref":{  
    "target_id":16  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "type": "attendance",    
  "title": "Testing Attendance",  
  "field_attendance_status":{  
  "und":{  
    "tid":3  
  }},  
  "og_group_ref":{
    "und": [
      { "target_id":16 }
    ]  

  }  
}
```

Either way, you should be able to verify the proper JSON to use by retrieving an existing node that has an og_group_ref.

For example, do a `GET` request (or just visit in a browser):

`?q=[my-api-endpoint]/node/123.json`

Then use a tool like jsonlint.com to inspect the JSON.

I'd also like to point out, that the JSON data you send to Services is *sometimes* dependant on the widget you have selected for the field's form element. See here for more details: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/159292/10645

Answer (score 0):

I have tried posting group content but didn't work in all field widgets (select, checkbox or auto complete)

I see there exist an issue with that field **og_group_ref** take a look at that [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159149/setting-og-with-services-module) have an answer with a patch hope to solve the issue.